# How can I get python stack trace information using GDB?

Tags: python, gdb

I am using GDB to debug a segmentation fault in my python application on Kubuntu 12.04. 
Supposedly GDB version 7 has built-in macros for extracting information about the python stack (http://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html), but I am having trouble getting it to work. I have installed python-dbg.

When I ask for a python stack trace in GDB, the result looks like this:

```
(gdb) py-bt
#5 (unable to read python frame information)
#16 (unable to read python frame information)
#26 (unable to read python frame information)
...
```

My GDB version is 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2, Python is 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.

Answer (score 19):

Here's the problem: to have access to debugging symbols in GDB, you must invoke a different binary: "python-dbg" instead of "python" (found this in /usr/share/doc/python2.7-dbg/README.debug).

Comment: Suprising how this is not mentioned in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging or anywhere else I could find. Thanks Luke.

Comment: This isn't true. You just have to get debugging symbols that match the python you are using. There can be gotchas if dealing with a virtualenv as that python may not match your system's python. There is a great writeup at https://www.podoliaka.org/2016/04/10/debugging-cpython-gdb/

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu 16.04 I managed to get Python stack trace in Python 3.5 by:

1. Installing `python3-dbg` and `python3-dev`:

   `$ sudo apt install python3-dbg python3-dev`

   `python3-dbg` package comes with short documentation how to use it in `/usr/share/doc/python3-dbg/README.debug` which I will use in the next step.
2. Appending unpacked GDB helper script `/usr/share/doc/python3.5/gdbinit.gz` to `~/.gdbinit`:

   `zcat /usr/share/doc/python3.5/gdbinit.gz >> ~/.gdbinit`

Now gdb will be able to find symbols for Python binary and `py-bt` works for displaying Python stack trace in gdb:

```
$ gdb -p 4762
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 4762
[New LWP 4852]
[New LWP 4853]
[New LWP 4854]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f38e43deb5d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq", line 80, in <module>
    Gtk.main()
(gdb)
```

Comment: my gdbinit.gz on Ubuntu 16.04 contains many commands like `pystack` but there is no `py-bt`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why is `python 3.5` even though I have already installed `python 3.6` ?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it is not possible to get debuginfo; for example if you are using conda Python, these packages do not come with debuginfo. It turns out that py-spy (https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) has a more robust implementation of Python backtrace dumping that doesn't rely on having accurate debug symbols available. However, as it also uses ptrace, you will have to detach gdb first. Here's how to make it work:

- Do your thing in gdb, getting to the breakpoint you want to get the Python backtrace for.
- Make gdb pass through SIGSTOP with `handle SIGSTOP noprint nostop pass`
- Pause the process with `signal SIGSTOP`
- Detach gdb with `detach`. Note the PID
- Run `py-spy dump --pid $PID` in another terminal. This gives you your backtrace.
- You can keep running gdb with `attach $PID`. Note that you can continue the process even if it is SIGSTOP'ed and it will run as normal, and will continue to be paused if you detach again

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps someone: The binary is named `python2.7-dbg` on my Debian system, coming from the `python2.7-dbg` package. I also installed the `python2.7-dev` package and `apt-get source python2.7-dbg`, so that `gdb` could find the source files to the Python interpreter.

With all this in place, I managed to debug the `SIGSEGV` I was running into: https://bugs.python.org/issue34870

Comment: how can we use python2.7-dbg

Comment: @NathanB Use `gdb /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg --args yourscript.py` to start it (note, the binary is probably `python3-dbg` these days, coming from the `python3-dbg` package). Then, place breakpoints (inside the Python interpreter) and use `run` to to start the interpreter in debug mode.  For more GDB documentation, use e.g. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/